# Deployd : adding array data via web UI

Tags: angularjs, deployd

How to add array data via web UI under deployd dashboard? It always shows dialog "not valid array". deployd v0.8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially I too faced same issue.Then figured out that adding square brackets fixed it.
Example:

```
[
    "1",
    "2",
    3,
    true,
    {
        "Tes":"Test"
    }
]
```

Comment: Only need to add, that there exist numeric rows, under web UI,  which don't mean anything and confuse people. 10x.